# ReactJS ReactDOM Render for Separate Pages

Tags: reactjs

I am in the process of migrating my pages from html and jquery to using React and I am aware that React Router and Redux are methods to handle routing when building a react application, but for the time being, I was wondering how I can change my setup to be able to render different react components for different pages. At the moment, I am able to render one react component when my index page is loaded, but I thought I could add another `ReactDOM.render()` beneath it and target a different div id for the component on a different page, but I noticed an error, `Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element`. Is this related to not using a react router or something else?

here is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ActivityFeed from './components/App/ActivityFeed/ActivityFeed';
import CreateAnnotation from './components/App/Annotation/CreateAnnotation';


ReactDOM.render(<ActivityFeed />, document.getElementById('annotation-card'));
ReactDOM.render(<CreateAnnotation />, document.getElementById('annotation-form'));
```

Here is `<CreateAnnotation/>`:
import React from 'react';

```
//GET /api/activity-feed and set to state

    export default class CreateAnnotation extends React.Component {
        constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);
            this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {
                notifications: [],
                reportLinks: [],
                files: []
            }
        }

        render() {  
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
            )
        }

    }
```

Here is the view file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    {{> app/app-head}}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="annotation-form"></div>
    {{> general/bundle-js}}
</body>
</html>
```

`{{> general/bundle-js}}`:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM renders a React element into the DOM in the supplied container 
and return a reference to the component (or returns null for stateless 
components). If the React element was previously rendered into 
container , this will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM 
as necessary to reflect the latest React element.
```

Technically speaking you cant render more than one React element into the DOM with multiple ReactDOM render function as it would always replace the previous rendered DOM.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html

The right way to do is to create multiple components and import them into App.js file. Then, your index.js file is supposed to import App.js file 
as one whole component, with ReactDOM only renders App.js as a single component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detail. This is a lack of understanding of the DOM details, but if I were targeting different container div tags as shown in the `index.js` tag that only existed on independent pages, wouldn't this be a single ReactDOM render per DOM? Or is the DOM storing information across the pages?

Also, do you mind elaborating on the create multiple component and import them into `app.js`. So you are saying import components into my server file and then import the server into my react `index.js` file?

Comment: Okay could you explain more of what you mean by `targeting different container div tags as shown in the index.js tag that only existed on independent pages` ?